# Flutter Getting Error While Running: java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Tags: windows, flutter, gradle

I am trying to install flutter to my new computer. Everything seems fine in flutter doctor but when i run my app I get an error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x16545f8f) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x16545f8f
```

How can i fix this . Please help

Answer (score 2):

You can run your project by opening Android module in Android studio. Go to

> Tools->Flutter->Open for Editing in Android Studio

**Why are you facing this error?**

Gradle 6 is not fully compatible with java 16. Use Java 11 will resolve the issue. [Download JDK 11 64 bit version](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html) and uninstall the current version of java.

You can check your java version by running `java -version` in command line interface.

**Note:** *Java 11 is ideal at this date (10 june,2021) so far.*

Comment: That really was the problem, thank you very much